# Regular Expression in Java Vs regular expression in Shell Script

Tags: java, regex, shell

My task was to write a regular expression in java and shell script which will validate all strings contaning only a single digit and any number of characters preceded or followed by that digit.

I wrote `[a-z]*[0-9]{1}[a-z]*` and it worked fine for **Java** but it is not at all working for **Shell Script**
Can anyone please help me to create a regular esxpression meeting my requirement in **Shell Script**

**Edit** *(from comments)*:
I tried with `grep` but it did not gave me useful results. [...] If the string validates I want to perform certain operations. So I used it like

```
if [$password eq [a-z]*[0-9]{1}[a-z]]; then 
    # "do this" 
else 
    # "do that" 
fi
```

Could you put some light on syntax differences in Java and shell script related to regular expressions?

Comment: Which scripting language?  Which operating system?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using in the shell?

Comment: what did you mean regex in shell script? by which tool? grep? how does your shell cmd containing the regex look like? btw the {1} could be omitted

Comment: @duffymo - scripting language - shell script OS - RHL

Comment: @ Mark Byers and Kent - i am just doing 
if [$password -eq [a-z]*[0-9]{1}[a-z]*];
then
do this
else
do that
fi

Thanks in advance

Comment: Bourne shell?  Korn shell?  C shell?  Maybe this will help you: http://www.staff.tugraz.at/reinfried.o.peter/unix/regular.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify which tool shall evaluate the regexp in the shell environment. But most tools will not recognize the `{1}` part. This part is not necessary anyway, because a `[0-9]` alone stand also for exactly one occurrence.

The shell script part would look like this:

```
if [[ "$var" =~ ^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][a-zA-Z]*$ ]]; then
    echo matching
else
    echo not matching
fi
```

The key parts are:

- use the `[[` expression, not the `[` one, because the former supports pattern matching (via `==`) and regexp matching (via `=~`)
- The `=~`, like most regexp libraries, will return `true` if the pattern matches *any* part of the string, not necessarily the complete string. For example `[a-z]*[0-9][a-z]*` would match `foo123bar456bla` because the pattern matches the `3bar` part with "zero occurrences of the first `[a-z]`, one occorrence of `[0-9]` and three occurrences of the second `[a-z]`". Therefore is is necessary to pin the regexp to the start and the end of the string using `^` and `$`.

In Java:

```
String var = ...;
if( var.matches("[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][a-zA-Z]*") )
    System.out.println("matches");
```

Here the `String.matches` implicitly matches the complete string. That's all a bit fuddled by history.

Comment: Thanks for your response...
i tried with grep but it didnot gave me useful result.
basically i want to use it in if statement and if the string validates i want to perform certain operations.
so i used it like 
if [$password eq [a-z]*[0-9]{1}[a-z]];
then
"do this"
else
"do that"
fi
could you put some light on syntax diff in java and shell script related to regular expression

Comment: @omkarsohani: please move your comment into the question itself, because it is important for the answer. People searching for similar information in the future might not find the information otherwise.

Comment: for java my code rather my regular expression is working as i already said.But the same regular expression is not working for shell script.